# Django ORM: How to find all instances with unique names which has the lowest value?

Tags: django

I've got queryset with 50+ instances:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(...).order_by['price']
```

Product model has:

```
store = models.ForeignKey('Store',...)
```

Each store has 10 products in the current queryset and there are 5 different stores in total. I'm trying to get one product from each store with a minimum price

Answer (score 2):

fetch the stores and then fetch the products from them, choose the first one after arranging them in ascending order

```
stores = Store.objects.all()
for st in stores:
    product = Product.objects.fiter(store=st).order_by('-price')[:1]
    print(product)
```

Comment: @wim 
Is it possible to do it in one SQL request? With annotate and SubQuery?